# Word connections

Tags: word, language, no-computers

I am trying a new kind of puzzle so feel free to leave constructive comments and opinions! Thank you!

---

The objective of this puzzle is to connect 2 words by using a chain of words that connects each other.

For example,

- a 2 word chain solution for the following :

  > Connect the words **air** and **chart**

  Could be :

  > **airflow** > **flowchart**

**Rules**

- No spaces are allowed.
- Every words in the chain must also be connected by an intermediary word.(ex. **flow** in the above example)

---

Here is the real one, good luck!

> Connect the words **play** and **out**

Can you find

- a 2 word chain?
- a 4 word chain?

---

**NOTE**

I am aware that using some internet tools could make this puzzle drastically easier so if possible, please refrain from doing so.

Comment: "*The connection between 2 words must be a word too.*" - does this mean the connecting words like airflow and flowchart, or are you also specifying that the words like flow have to be actual words?

Comment: @randal'thor it means that "flow" is also a word. Maybe my explanation is ambiguous...

Comment: Sooo what do you guys think? Too easy? Too boring? Should I make more? Should I not? No need to be nice, just honest ;p. I did get 2 downvotes out of 10 views so I suppose it is not that fun.

Comment: I like the idea: it makes for a sort of bite-sized challenge, although it's quite simple and there are loads of puzzles like this out there. If you really want to stretch your creativity, why not try to do something more advanced with this idea? For instance, word chains in more than one dimension, or using those intermediary words like "flow" to construct something else?

Comment: I'm downvoting, because the explanation could be better. It's rather confusing by what you mean with the connections

Comment: Based on your note, I added the [tag:no-computers] tag for you.

Comment: You've inspired me :-) [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47981/5373) is the sort of thing I was thinking of when I said "word chains in more than one dimension".

Comment: @randal'thor glad I could help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2-word chain:

> **playtime** $\rightarrow$ **timeout**

3-word chain:

> **playable** $\rightarrow$ **ablest** $\rightarrow$ **stout**

4-word chain:

> **playtime** $\rightarrow$ **timeout** $\rightarrow$ **outlay** $\rightarrow$ **layout**

- with spaces:

  - > **playtime** $\rightarrow$ **timetable** $\rightarrow$ **tabletop** $\rightarrow$ **top out** (not sure if this last one is valid)
  - > **playboy** $\rightarrow$ **boyfriend** $\rightarrow$ **friendzone** $\rightarrow$ **zone out**

5-word chain:

> **playoff** $\rightarrow$ **offbeat** $\rightarrow$ **beatable** $\rightarrow$ **ablest** $\rightarrow$ **stout**

Comment: another possiblity: rot13 cynlbss > bssorng > orngobk > obkbhg

Comment: @Will Sure those last two are valid words?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beatbox) and [yes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boxout) (or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxout) for the latter if you're adventurous))

Comment: Your 2 word connection is correct... Thank you for making me realize many problems with my puzzle. I will add some specifications.

Comment: Another possibility if those last two don't please you would be: cynlbss > bssunaq > unaqubyq > ubyqbhg

Comment: @Will Nice! Want to post that as an answer of your own?

Comment: Good job! you found a correct 2 and 4 word chain connection!(Although the 4 word one is a bit different than mine)

Comment: @MikeQ The rules hadn't yet been clarified when I wrote those parts of my answer. But it doesn't really matter, since the question only asked for chains of length 2 and 4, not 3 and 5.

Answer (score 4):

I'm borrowing part of [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)'s answer for my 4-word chain.

4-Word Chain:

> Playtime → timeout → outclass → classroom

Comment: That ends with the wrong word ...

Comment: @randal'thor you're right, it doesnt make sense XD. My sister came over and helped me correct this. (Too early in the morning my brain isn't working well)

Comment: The last word must finish by "out" to properly connect the 2 words with your chain.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoyed this puzzle thanks for sharing!

> 1) Playdate > Date-Night > Night-Out 
>  2) Playground > Groundbreak > Breakout
>  3) Playlist > Listen > Enclose > Closeout

Not sure if 2 phrases are ok for answer 1 though...

Answer (score 1):

2-word chain:

> playwork -> workout

3-word chains:

> playback -> backlog -> logout
>  playhouse -> housebreak -> breakout
>  playoff -> offhand -> handout

4-word chain:

> playbill -> billboard -> boardwalk -> walkout

5-word chains:

> playpen -> penname -> nameplate -> platemail -> mailout
>  playclothes -> clothesline -> lineup -> uptake -> takeout

6-word chain:

> playground -> groundhog -> hogwash -> washpot -> potshoot -> shootout