# Word connection squares!

Tags: word, language, no-computers

This puzzle is in the spirit of [Word connections](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47931/5373), but is a more elaborate version of the same idea.

In each puzzle, you have a square of seven words of the following form:

```
A       B
C   D   E
F       G
```

Each of the letters A-G represents a word, and each pair of adjacent words (AC, CF, CD, DE, BE, EG) forms a new, longer word. At the start you are given only A, B, F, and G; **your task is to find D**.

---

### Square #1 (easier)

```
DATA            FACE
 ??      ??      ??
ROLL            MARK
```

### Square #2 (harder)

```
LOVE            BALD
 ??      ??      ??
SONG            ROLL
```

---

I don't know whether these are uniquely solvable. I hope they are. If not, I'll add some kind of restriction.

All feedback welcome! It's my first puzzle of this sort.

Comment: The nested level of mystery is delicious and could of course go arbitrarily deep. A local newspaper carries an almost-as-interesting one-sided version with given mystery-word lengths.

Comment: When I saw this comment in my inbox, I knew it was from you, @humn. There's a certain poetry about your feedback as well as your questions :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Number 1 is:

> ```
> DATA      FACE
> BANK NOTE BOOK
> ROLL      MARK
> ```

This puzzle reminds me of a game from a podcast I listen to wherein they connect movie titles. For example, *Purple Rain Man* = *Purple Rain* + *Rain Man*. Movie titles might make for an interesting themed variant of your puzzle.

Comment: *GentlePurpleRain* = *Gentle Purple* + *Purple Rain*?

Answer (score 8):

Number 2 is:

> ```
> LOVE      BALD
> BIRD LIME RICK
> SONG      ROLL
> ```

(I'm finding #1 harder; I have one of the intermediate words but the others are eluding me.)

Comment: Good job! (And shows how hard it is to judge difficulty beforehand. I was sure the right-hand half of this would make it especially difficult for people to get, but evidently not.)

Comment: Actually it made it easier. How many words are there starting BALD, after all?

Comment: Never heard of BIRD-LIME and definitely would not have gotten that with the `no-computers` tag.

Comment: I promise I didn't cheat!

Comment: I believe you. I also believe that you are illegally poaching birds in your spare time. ;-)

Comment: Well, better that than doing it *legally*.