# What is a Doubtful Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Doubtful Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| DOUBTFUL WORD™ | NOT DOUBTFUL WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| FORAGE | HUNT |
| ONION | GARLIC |
| OTHERWISE | DIFFERENT |
| IMAGE | PICTURE |
| QUESTION | ANSWER |
| LITERATE | LIBRARY |
| HEADACHE | MIGRAINE |
| WITLESS | STUPID |
| INFANCY | YOUTH |
| MICROSCOPE | ZOOM |
| FRIENDSHIP | ALLIANCE |
| SUBSCRIBE | REGISTER |
| ATROPHY | WASTE |
| BACKWARDS | REAR |

Here is a CSV version:

```
DOUBTFUL WORD™, NOT DOUBTFUL WORD™
FORAGE, HUNT
ONION, GARLIC
OTHERWISE, DIFFERENT
IMAGE, PICTURE
QUESTION, ANSWER
LITERATE, LIBRARY
HEADACHE, MIGRAINE
WITLESS, STUPID
INFANCY, YOUTH
MICROSCOPE, ZOOM
FRIENDSHIP, ALLIANCE
SUBSCRIBE, REGISTER
ATROPHY, WASTE
BACKWARDS, REAR
```

Comment: You might consider removing READER from the list of Not Doubtful Words, since Oxford English Dictionary (one of two big authorities on English) lists [ER](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/er) as an exclamation.

Comment: [WAS](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/was) [TE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/te) is also splittable.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with word occurrence frequency in a text corpus/ngrams?

Comment: @CipherRiddle no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Doubtful Word is

> A word that can be split into two substrings both of which are also words, whereas Not Doubtful words cannot.
>  For example:
>  "Atrophy" -> "A" + "Trophy", or
>  "Literate" -> "Liter" + "Ate".
>
>  As such if spacing is unclear we may be **doubtful** about the intended meaning of Doubtful Words; we may be unsure if they are one word or two.

The exceptions I see are slightly obscure:

> "Reverse" -> "Re" + "Verse".
>  The somewhat new word "Re" came up in [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48273/some-what-not-with-standing-word-connections#comment147125_48284) recently too, but it seems to have crept into the English language as it is used to specify that the following text is *regarding* some referenced subject.
>
>  "Zoom" -> "Zo" + "Om".
>  "Zo" - a Tibetan breed of cattle, developed by crossing the yak with common cattle (only the "dzo" spelling is in the O.E.D., but "zo" is in Collins as a variant).
>  "Om" - the most sacred mantra in Hinduism and Tibetan Buddhism.

Others pointed out by Silenus and Rubio (respectively) are:

> "Reader" -> "Read" + "Er".
>  "Er" - a natural utterance, when one hesitates.
>
>  "Waste" -> "Was" + "Te".
>  "Te" - the syllable used for the seventh note or subtonic of any scale (As in "do-re-mi-fa-so-la-**te**-do" and variants thereof),

OP edit:

> It's a doubtful word, because it is unsure, it has "split" opinions.

Comment: Didn't posted the answer due to the "re" factor. I guess there is something else in there which makes it doubtful.

Comment: Reverse could also be Rev (as in revving up an engine) + Erse (an old word for Gaelic).

Comment: Answer is correct good work! Sorry about the "re" thing I wasn't aware of this being a real formal word (ignore it). To be accepted try to explain why it's doubtful.

Comment: Doubtful, perhaps because it also contains two words. Doubt and Full? (Ful=Full, maybe)

Comment: @MOehm "rev" an abbreviation (yours is of "revolution" but also of "reverend" [clerical] or "Revelations" [book of the bible]) .

Comment: @Melkor added my interpretation of the reasoning.

Comment: Migraine could be MIG+RAINE. MIG= Army aircraft-type thingy and Google says RAINE= Kingdom and French for Queen. ALso, Different=DIFFER+ENT. ENT= Acronym for Ear,Nose and throat, a term used mainly in medical science.

Comment: Rev = word eg Revs per minute; Erse = Very dated word not sure; MiG = A name; Raine = Cannot find evidence as a word. I am skeptical about these, as they don't seem like acceptable words. @JonathanAllan your explanation for why it is doubtful is good, but not what I was looking for. I think what I am looking for fits better.

Comment: If you'll accept "er" as a word, then zoom, which is listed as not a Doubtful Word™ would be "zoo" + "m" considering "mmmmmm" can also be a similar expression - which makes me hesitate to agree with this.

Comment: @Zxyrra well "er" is actually listed as a word in the OED and is acceptable in Scrabble in both the UK and the US.

Comment: WASTE is also splittable to WAS / TE, see comments under question ...

Comment: @Rubio added, and added another: Zo / Om.

Comment: For what it's worth, "re" is the second note of the major scale (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/re)