# A crossword to appease all

Tags: wordplay, crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

[image: A crossword grid]

*(Click for full size)*

**Across**

```
1. Steal extremely experimental metal song or 26-across maybe (6)
4. "Wardrobes malfunctioned", most rang for short interval (8)
10. Future engineer edits New York, USA's voting time? (7)
11. Plain type distraction loses 26-across from the get-go (7)
12. Tuck from Sherwood Forest apartment sounded pleasant (5)
13. Lean or thin letters for point lists (5)
15. Youth's hiding, not at home as well (3)
16. Stare at backward tie? (4)
18. Beg, on the street, US state's head of transportation with 17-down* points? (9)
21. Old timer Will stripped record I half-called erroneous (9)
23. Defrost a flank? Excuse me... (4)
26. Be in debt to company's network segment? (3)
27. Youtuber characters came back to refute Japanese portal (5)
29. Perhaps 9 to 5 chore involved pigment? (5)
30. Happiness circulated to alien probe (7)
32. Jerk cutting gem's visual subtleties (7)
33. Easy-to-maintain pet mammal initially had advantage, not oddly through (8)
34. Fisherman untidily trimmed gnarled cord or string (6)
```

**Down**

```
1. Inform colony member I'd stun accidentally? (6)
2. Encountering each 6-down confused clerk (7)
3. Head villager, ignited within, evacuated everyone for best (5)
5. Foe even returned letter in the end? No way (5)
6. Have a title, a title some desired (3)
7. Associated costly essential grub with debts, accepting loan at last (7)
8. Experienced musician left half of instrument in Melbourne briefly (8)
9. Entrancing publicity poster detailed 1984 society possibly (8)
14. Intelligent hound put Asian currency in central exchange (5)
17. Truant half-heartedly bet small cube (5)
19. Unwillingness from 51, set in belief, lacking knowledge (8)
20. Photographing renovation of this exit for minutes? In a second (8)
22. Fork, for instance, old OS X release's variation of preload (7)
24. Unusually athletic model dropped moral type of case a lawyer might have? (7)
25. Casually discarded Spooner's letter for 2-down (6)
28. Search by Microsoft lead to Olympic game ceremonies (5)
29. Stretch 15-across* cushion without cover frequently (5)
31. Christmas worker Frost not initally kind? (3)
```

**(6)**

P.S. There are no cryptic double definitions.

Comment: No double definitions, eh? This is briliiant!

Comment: Ooh, interesting.

Comment: I've figured out the gimmick and I *think* I know how to extract after.

Comment: Just added a missing asterisk to 29-down

Comment: Found this on Meta. Took me years back with solving them. Pleasing theme.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a very cleverly constructed puzzle. If you are into crosswords, please consider giving this a try before reading the answer.

The postscript says that there are no cryptic double definitions in this crossword. And there's a good reason:

> It is technically not possible, or at least not convenient. Each clue consists of a cryptic clue and of a plain clue next to each other in no specified order. Double cryptic definitions would turn the clues into triple answers with only two of them matching.
>
>  The two clues mean that the crossword can be filled in twice: once with the cryptic clues and once with the plain clues. (I only noticed that the plain clues are clues to the same crossword after I had solved some of the cryptics, so I solved this in two steps: Cryptics first; plain clues after that. I've now rewritten the answer to treat both crosswords simultaneously.)
>
>  Some clues have a cross-reference with an asterisk. These cross-references refer to the corresponsing answers of the other crossword. (I hadn't noticed that, but the author told me so in a comment.)

The solution to the clues:

> (Cryptic definitions and answers are printed in bold. Plain definitions and answers are set in curly braces. At first I had two different sections for cryptic and plain crossword, but I've now condensed them into a single block.)
>
> **Across**
>
> 1. Steal extremely experimental **metal** {song or 26-across maybe}
>   — {NUMBER}; **26** is TWO  — **NICKEL**: NICK (steal) + E[xperimenta]L
> 4. "{Wardrobes} malfunctioned", most rang for **short interval**
>   — {ARMOIRES}  — **ANGSTROM**: (MOST RANG)*
> 10. **Future** engineer edits New York, {USA's voting time}?
>   — {TUESDAY}  — **DESTINY**: (EDITS)* + NY
> 11. {Plain} **type** distraction loses 26-across from the get-go
>   — {VANILLA}  — **VERSION**: [di]VERSION, minus TWO from the beginning
> 12. {Tuck from Sherwood Forest} **apartment** sounded pleasant
>   — {FRIAR}  — **SUITE**: homophone of sweet
> 13. Lean or thin letters for **point** {lists}
>   — {TILTS} —  **NORTH**: hidden in leaN OR THin
> 15. Youth's hiding, **not at home** {as well}
>   — {TOO}  — **OUT**: hidde in yOUTh
> 16. {Stare at} backward **tie**?
>   — {OGLE}  — **DRAW**: WARD< (separate back-ward)
> 18. {Beg, on the street}, **US state's** head of transportation with 17-down* points?
>   — {PANHANDLE}  — **TENNESSEE**: T[ransportation] + 8 compass points; {17} is EIGHT
> 21. {Old timer} Will stripped record I half-called **erroneous**
>   — {HOURGLASS}  — **ILLOGICAL**: w[IL]l + LOG + I CAL[led]
> 23. {Defrost} a flank? Excuse me... (4)
>   — {THAW}  — **AHEM**: A HEM
> 26. {Be in debt to} **company's** network segment?
>   — {OWE}  — **TWO**: hidden in neTWOrk
> 27. Youtuber characters came back to **refute** {Japanese portal} (5)
>   — {TORII}  — **REBUT**: [you]TUBER<
> 29. {Perhaps 9 to 5} chore involved **pigment**?
>   — {RATIO}  — **OCHRE**: (CHORE)*
> 30. **Happiness** circulated to alien {probe}
>   — {INSPECT}  — **ELATION**: (TO ALIEN)*
> 32. Jerk cutting gem's **visual** {subtleties}
>   — {NUANCES}  — **OPTICAL**: TIC in OPAL
> 33. {Easy-to-maintain pet} **mammal** initially had advantage, not oddly through
>   — {GOLDFISH}  — **HEDGEHOG**: H[ad] + EDGE (advantage) + even letters of tHrOuGh
> 34. **Fisherman** untidily trimmed gnarled {cord or string}
>   — {THREAD}  — **ANGLER**: (GNARLE[d])*
>
> **Down**
>
> 1. {Inform} **colony member** I'd stun accidentally?
>   — {NOTIFY}  — **NUDIST**: (ID STUN)*
> 2. {Encountering} each 6-down confused **clerk** (7)
>   — {MEETING}  — **CASHIER**: (EACH SIR)*, 6d is SIR
> 3. {Head villager}, ignited within, evacuated everyone for **best**
>   — {ELDER}  — **ELITE**: LIT in E[veryone]E
> 5. {Foe} even returned letter in the end? **No way**
>   — {RIVAL}  — **NEVER**: EVEN< + [lette]R
> 6. {Have a title}, **a title** some desired
>   — {OWN}  — **SIR**: hidden (some) in seSIRed
> 7. {Associated} **costly** essential grub with debts, accepting loan at last
>   — {RELATED}  — **RUINOUS**: g[RU]b + [loa]N in IOUS
> 8. {Experienced} **musician** left half of instrument in Melbourne briefly
>   — {SEASONED}  — **MINSTREL**: INSTR[ument] in MEL[bourne]
> 9. **Entrancing** publicity poster detailed {1984 society possibly}
>   — {DYSTOPIA}  — **HYPNOTIC**: HYP[e] + NOTIC[e]
> 14. {Intelligent} **hound** put Asian currency in central exchange
>   — {SMART}  — **HYENA**: YEN in exc[HA]nge
> 17. Truant half-heartedly **bet** {small cube}
>   — {EIGHT}  — **WAGER**: WAG[g]ER
> 19. **Unwillingness** from 51, set in belief, {lacking knowledge} (8)
>   — {NESCIENT}  — **NOLITION**: LI (51) in NOTION
> 20. {Photographing} renovation of this exit for **minutes? In a second**
>   — {SHOOTING}  — **SIXTIETH**: (THIS EXIT)*
> 22. {Fork, for instance}, **old OS X release's** variation of preload
>   — {UTENSIL}  — **LEOPARD**: (PRELOAD)*
> 24. Unusually athletic model dropped **moral** {type of case a lawyer might have?}
>   — {ATTACHE}  — **ETHICAL**: (A[t]HLETIC)*
> 25. {Casually discarded} Spooner's letter for **2-down**
>   — {TOSSED}  — **TELLER**: A syllable-wise Spoonerism of LETTER
> 28. Search by Microsoft lead to Olympic **game** {ceremonies}
>   — {RITES}  — **BINGO**: BING (MS search) + O[lympic]
> 29. {Stretch 15-across*} cushion without cover **frequently**
>   — {REACH}; 15 is OUT  — **OFTEN**: s[OFTEN]
> 31. {Christmas worker} **Frost** not initally kind?
>   — {ELF}  — **ICE**: [n]ICE

The completed crossword grids:

> ```
>          N U M B E R   A R M O I R E S         N I C K E L   A N G S T R O M
>          O   E   L   D   I   W   E   E         U   A   L   H   E   I   U   I
>          T U E S D A Y   V A N I L L A         D E S T I N Y   V E R S I O N
>          I   T   E   S   A       A   S         I   H   T   P   E       N   S
>          F R I A R   T I L T S   T O O         S U I T E   N O R T H   O U T
>          Y   N       O       M   E   N         T   E       O       Y   U   R
>            O G L E   P A N H A N D L E           D R A W   T E N N E S S E E
>          S       I   I   E   R       D         S       A   I   O   N       L
>          H O U R G L A S S   T H A W           I L L O G I C A L   A H E M
>          O   T   H       C       T   T         X   E   E       I       T   T
>          O W E   T O R I I   R A T I O         T W O   R E B U T   O C H R E
>          T   N       I   E   E   A   S         I   P       I   I   F   I   L
>          I N S P E C T   N U A N C E S         E L A T I O N   O P T I C A L
>          N   I   L   E   T   C   H   E         T   R   C   G   N   E   A   E
>          G O L D F I S H   T H R E A D         H E D G E H O G   A N G L E R
> ```

And now?

> The two solved grids have some letters in common.
>
> ```
>          N . . . E .   A . . . . R . .
>          .   .   L   .   .   .   .   .
>          . . . . . . Y   V . . . . . .
>          I   .   .   .   .       .   S
>          . . I . .   . . . T .   . . .
>          .   .       O       .   .   .
>            . . . .   . . N . . . . . E
>          S       .   I   .   .       .
>          . . . . G . . . .   . H . .
>          .   .   .       .       T   T
>          . W .   . . . . .   . . . . .
>          .   .       I   .   .   .   .
>          . . . . . . .   . . . . C . .
>          .   .   .   .   .   .   .   E
>          . . . . . . . .   . . . . . .
> ```
>
> The letters read:
>
>    Nearly visit one sight twice (6)
>
>  The enumeration (6) comes from the question, it's below the clues.

The final answer:

> The above is, of course, another double clue:
>
>    Nearly visit one **sight** {twice} — {DOUBLE} — **VISION**: VISI[t] ON[e]
>
>  giving the overall answer **DOUBLE VISION**.

The title:

> This puzzle has two crosswords in one grid, so it is for everyone: For those who like cryptics and for those who like plain clues. (Obviously, this excludes those who don't like crosswords at all.)

Comment: Gah, you beat me to the solve. Nice work!

Comment: Although I don't think you're done...

Comment: Common letters?

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: Nice work! Since you're almost done, these might help with the write-up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO914.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZgPC.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9XIx.png

Comment: Oh, silly me, that's what the (6) is for.

Comment: Nailed it :) I should note that 1-across is the other reason for the double-def comment, and * was *meant* to indicate a cross-grid reference but I didn't realise 29-down was missing one until you'd already solved the grids.

Comment: Thanks. That is a superbly constructed puzzle and it was a satisfying solve, even if I needed your nudge to see what that last sentence was about.

Comment: Please do a making-of writeup for this, because this needs way more recognition (and rep) than it's going to get. Absolutely amazing puzzle, beautifully intricate and beautifully executed.

Answer (score 23):

### Wrap-up: The making of "A crossword to appease all"

*This is not a solution to the puzzle but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48273/some-what-not-with-standing-word-connections/48343#48343).*

**Caution:** This post contains spoilers for the puzzle.

---

The inspirations for this innocuous-looking crossword were [MIT2017's Stackuro](http://solutions.monsters-et-manus.com/hunt/puzzle/stackuro.html) and [SUMS2014's Cryptish](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/ub/sums/puzzlehunt/2014/puzzles/A4S4_Cryptish.pdf). I wanted to try my hand at writing an unusual cryptic, and hit upon the idea of using one clue to fill two grids, with the grid and enumeration playing double duty. This solidified the penultimate step of taking common letters quickly, since looking for commonalities between two similar items is a typical and intuitive extraction mechanic.

The answer came soon after as a nice thematic phrase with an equal number of letters in both parts. It seemed obvious that the hidden message should be a double clue that gave the answer.

There were two requirements this clue had to achieve:

- The cryptic had to be simple. It's easy to fall into the trap of having a difficult last step, which gets frustrating for the solver when they have 99% of the puzzle solved but are stuck at the finish line. In addition, there are no cross letters to help the solver here.
- The clue had to be short. The final clue clocks in at 24 letters, an average of 1.6 letters per row, which is already plenty as a gridding restriction.

Ideally the clue would give both parts of the answer in order, but given the above two constraints and the niceness of the chosen clue's surface, I decided to let it slide.

From here, the first hard part was making the grids. For this I used the crossword construction software [TEA & Sympathy](http://www.crosswordman.com/sympathy.html), although there are alternatives out there (e.g. [Crossword Compiler](http://www.crossword-compiler.com/)). I couldn't figure out how to have two instances of TEA & Sympathy open at once, and ended up exploiting the custom clue numberings feature to fill the second grid in parallel.

Constructing the grid was a repeated process of filling from the top, aiming for words which would provide letters for the message in approximately the right locations. For instance, I started filling the top-left so that 1-across provided the first two letters of the message, then made the row below give the 5th letter, with a mental note to clue the 3rd and 4th letters using what is now 4-across. Although ideally you'd want a nice spread of message letter locations, I knew that I'd want to skew the distribution so that the top half gave more letters, since things would only get more restrictive the more the grid gets filled.

One thing worth noting here is the unusually high number of blocked out squares. A friend once told me that, for a 15 by 15 grid with white squares on odd rows, the number of blocked out squares before the midpoint is usually 6 to 8, with 8 being more lax and a potential sign of a themed crossword. However, in this puzzle we have 10:

[image]

Initially I had 8 blocked out squares, but found that I kept getting stuck when filling, and gradually blocked out more as I went to make it easier for myself. This provided some 3-letter words which simplified bridging the gaps. I still wanted the grid to be "nice" — each answer still had to have at least 50% of letters being cross letters, and of course the grid had to be symmetric. Additionally, the grid had to be interconnected enough so that there was sufficient linking between the four corners, since it's easy to accidentally make the corners too detached, causing solvers to be stuck on a particular corner due to a lack of cross letters that, so to speak, poke into the corner.

When choosing words, I focused more on getting the grid filled, making preference for common words. The

> NESCIENT / NOLITION

pair represent the least common of the bunch, used out of necessity. Little consideration for the resulting cryptic clues was made at this point, but if a choice was presented then I'd take surface reading into account. This resulted in some awkward to clue words which lack good definitions, in particular

> TUESDAY and SIXTIETH.

You can see how I went with those.

At one point I wanted a pair of two-word phrases with the same enumeration (e.g. NAME TAG and NOSE JOB), to add to the "looks like one crossword" presentation. Unfortunately, this didn't end up happening.

For the clues themselves, here are some general notes:

- I wanted there to be a clean split between the quick and cryptic portions, which meant no connecting words in between. This restriction made the surface reading tricky to sound nice in many cases.
- Due to needing to fit two separate definitions in one clue, surface readings on the whole were a bit awkward, but I tried my best to at least make them somewhat meaningful. As a result some quick clues were a little lax, but I compensated by providing quicks that were dead giveaways (which also serves as a hint to the puzzle's gimmick).
- In the final version, all the quick clues fill one grid and all the cryptic clues fill the other grid. At one point I considered making it mixed, so that when you solve a pair you would need to figure out which goes where. This would give more flexibility in the cryptics since I could choose which word of each pair to provide wordplay for, but in the end I decided that having a clear separation was nicer as a puzzle.
- Double definitions were avoided in the cryptic portion since, with three definitions, it seemed possible that a solver might be able to find an alternative answer for the wrong pair. The post-script was added after the quick's 1-across was changed to be a double definition to make that clue easier.

Finally, here's some notes on specific clues:

> 11a. The intention here was to drop two *letters* from the get-go (beginning) of DIVERSION to get VERSION. Now that I look at @MOehm's answer, I realise that this can also be interpreted as dropping the prefix DI-, which happens to means "two".
>
>  12a. In hindsight, the cryptic portion ("apartment sounded pleasant" → SUITE, homophone of SWEET) was not ideal due to the indicator being in the centre, making it ambiguous as to which answer is correct. Thankfully it's possible to disambiguate using cross letters.
>
>  16a. This clue demonstrates [elision](http://www.crosswordunclued.com/2011/11/elision.html), needing to split "backward" into "back WARD = DRAW = tie". Since the fodder is given verbatim I figured it was fair, and it was hard to resist.
>
>  18a. Usually, saying "[number] points" to indicate a chunk of [number] letters from NESW is less than ideal, but in TENNESSEE's case where there are eight of them it seemed fair. It's a somewhat lazy way to clue the state, but with restrictions in mind it seemed better than the alternatives I had, such as "#10 SE reportedly" (SE being Stack Exchange).
>
>  21a. "Old-timer", as in an elderly person, typically has a hyphen. To make the quick clue "Old timer" → HOURGLASS fairer, this was intentionally left out.
>
>  26a. Ideally one might have "company, proverbially" or similar here for the definition of TWO, but for the sake of surface I ended up opting for a question mark instead.
>
>  33a. At one point I accidentally had GOLD RUSH instead of GOLDFISH here, but that wouldn't have worked due to a mismatch in enumeration with HEDGEHOG. Of course, the enumeration could just be dropped from all clues, needing solvers to infer possibilities from the grid, but the puzzle didn't seem as nice this way. Had the answer been GOLD RUSH though, it'd have been ripe for a "Sonic boom" surface.
>
>  34a. The nested indicators "untidily (trimmed GNARLED)" is a little awkward here, but it was hard to make the surface sound good. The redundant quick clue "cord or string" was used to rule out STRING as a potential 6-letter answer.
>
>  3d. "For the best" sounds better for the surface of this clue, but "for best" is nicer in terms of wordplay (since the parallel is "the best" ↔ "the ELITE", rather than "the best" ↔ "ELITE"). Since the phrase "for better or worse" exists, I ended up going with the latter.
>
>  8d. "Melbourne, briefly" for MEL is a reference to a lesser-used abbreviation of Melbourne, Australia, rather than being a general indicator of taking an unspecified number of letters from the start (which would be unfair). MEL is also the IATA code for Melbourne Airport.
>
>  22d. As obscure as it may be, the intended surface reading of "preload" here is the [Linux software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preload_(software)).
>
>  28d. If "Search" as an alternative way of saying "search engine" feels dubious, the intended surface was to read "Search" as [Google Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search), and the word was placed at the start to hide its capitalisation.
>
>  29d. Depending on the setter and the clue, "cover" can refer to both the first and last letters of a word (as in a cushion cover, which surrounds its interior) or just the first letter (as in a lid). In this case it is the latter, which makes sense when one realises that this is a down clue.

This was a long read, and if you've gotten this far I hope that gave some useful insights into the construction of this puzzle. Overall I'm very glad with how it turned out, even though the grid and clues could be a bit better. If you're wondering how long this took, the answer is one whole day of powering through.

If there are any specific questions you'd like answered, feel free to leave a comment.